# Get nedele out of string before

Tags: php, string, explode

How can I get a needle out of a string by get it before a something?

CODE:

```
$test = "The quick (brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)";
```

I need to get The `quick` from the string

I have tried to use explode but then u can only get what is behind the needle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$test = "The quick (brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)";

$substr =  substr($test, 0, strpos($test, '(') - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo substr($test, 0, strpos($test, '('));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "The quick (brown fox jumps over the lazy dog)";
$result = explode("(", $test);

echo $result['0']; // The quick
```

Comment: I need to get all what is befor the "(" in 1 string

Comment: Edited my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$substr = end(explode(' ', rtrim(strstr($test, '(', true), ' ')));
```